# ¿Cómo evitar doble login en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy creando un sistema donde el objetivo es que solamente una persona por usuario pueda acceder al sistema, para esto tengo en mi BD dos tablas llamadas: users y accesos
Lo que estoy estoy haciendo es que al momento de logearse la persona 1, se guarde en mi DB el id de la sesión en las dos tablas,  si la persona 2 con el mismo usuario intenta acceder entonces  a la primer persona que inicio sesión lo saca del sistema.
Esto lo hago con ayuda con AJAX, comparando si el ultimo usuario que inicio tiene el mismo id de sesión entonces puede navegar sin problema, si no cierra sesión.

El problema es que esta petición ajax la realizo cada 10s, pero tendría problemas si 10000 personas o mas inician sesión, entonces se estará mandado la petición al servidor cada 10 segundos y esto podría saturar el servidor.

Intente con un campo de activo si inicia sesión es igual a 1 y si se cierra sesión es igual a 0, entonces descarte esto ya que si el usuario cierra el navegador entonces nunca cerro sesión y la persona no podrá acceder, también probé en utilizar un método ajax para que detecte si cierra el navegador pero no es muy confiable. Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema? se los agradecería mucho.

Dejo mi código php y js para que se visualice como lo hago:

Codigo JS:

```
 $(function() { 
    cron(); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
    function cron() {
         $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "closeuser.php", 
          data: { action: 1 }
          })
        .done(function(msg) {
            var trimmedString = msg.trim();
            console.log(trimmedString)
          if( trimmedString == 'success' ) {  // Valida si el server devolvió 'success'
                 location.href='logoutuser.php';
          }
        });
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        cron();
    }, 10000); // cada 10 segundos
});
```

Codigo PHP:

```
<?php

    require_once 'Connections/sesionunica.php';
    $connection_s = new sesionunica();
    
     if(!isset($_SESSION["id_user"])){ 
            echo"<script>location.href='index.php';</script>";  
        } 
    
    if(isset($_POST["action"])) { // Se pasa una acción
        switch(sprintf("%d", $_POST["action"])) { // ¿Qué acción?
            case 1:
                cerrar();
                break;
            default:
            echo "default";
        }
    }
    function cerrar(){
        $ses = session_id();
        $connection_s = new sesionunica();
        $userById = $connection_s->getUsers($_SESSION["id_user"]);
        if ($userById["id_sesion"] <> $ses) {
        echo "success"; 
        }
    }
    
    ?>
```

De igual manera no puedo usar websockets ya que se tiene problemas de accesibilidad con el servidor.

Comment: Yo utilizo firebase para detectar el inicio de sessión ,lo pones en tu javascript y cuando el usario se logue lo guardas y lo pones a escuchar ,asi no debes estar consultando tu db